JSON_TABLE Function For H2 Database
I am trying to create an alias for json_table command for H2 database so that i can wirte Unit tests for the same but when i tried various ways of creating it getting error everytime.
DROP ALIAS if exists JSON_TABLE;
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS JSON_TABLE AS '
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.lang.String;
java.sql.ResultSet jsonTable(java.lang.String json, java.lang.String key) throws java.sql.SQLException {
    org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet rs = new org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet();
    rs.addColumn("FIELD", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
    rs.addColumn("OLD_VALUE", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
    rs.addColumn("NEW_VALUE", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);

    org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        org.json.JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        rs.addRow(
            obj.optString("field", null),
            obj.optString("oldValue", null),
            obj.optString("newValue", null)
        );
    }
    return rs;
}';

this is what I tried for the view below also tried creating separate class and writing path here for the alias in that case it is not able to find the class.
the view:
CREATE
            OR REPLACE VIEW dummy.V AS
            SELECT ROWNUM        AS ID,
                   a.changed_at  AS "CHANGED_AT",
                   a.changed_by  AS "CHANGED_BY",
                   a.object_id   AS "OBJECT_ID",
                   a.order_id    AS "ORDER_ID",
                   a.order_type  AS "ORDER_TYPE",
                   a.object_type AS "OBJECT_TYPE",
                   a.action      AS "ACTION",
                   a.task_id     AS "TASK_ID",
                   jt.FIELD      AS FIELD,
                   jt.OLD_VALUE  AS OLD_VALUE,
                   jt.NEW_VALUE  AS NEW_VALUE
            FROM dummy.Table a,
                 json_table(
                         a.changes, '$[*]'
                     COLUMNS (
                         FIELD VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) PATH '$.field',
                         OLD_VALUE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) PATH '$.oldValue',
                         NEW_VALUE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) PATH '$.newValue'
                         )
                 ) jt

Error is :
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:7: error: illegal start of type\000d\000aimport java.sql.ResultSet;\000d\000a^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:7: error: <identifier> expected\000d\000aimport java.sql.ResultSet;\000d\000a                         ^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:8: error: illegal start of type\000d\000aimport java.sql.SQLException;\000d\000a^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:8: error: <identifier> expected\000d\000aimport java.sql.SQLException;\000d\000a                            ^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:9: error: illegal start of type\000d\000aimport java.sql.Types;\000d\000a^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:9: error: <identifier> expected\000d\000aimport java.sql.Types;\000d\000a                     ^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:10: error: illegal start of type\000d\000aimport org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet;\000d\000a^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:10: error: <identifier> expected\000d\000aimport org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet;\000d\000a                                   ^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:11: error: illegal start of type\000d\000aimport org.json.JSONArray;\000d\000a^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:11: error: <identifier> expected\000d\000aimport org.json.JSONArray;\000d\000a                         ^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:12: error: illegal start of type\000d\000aimport org.json.JSONObject;\000d\000a^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:12: error: <identifier> expected\000d\000aimport org.json.JSONObject;\000d\000a                          ^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:13: error: illegal start of type\000d\000aimport java.lang.String;\000d\000a^\000d\000a/org/h2/dynamic/JSON_TABLE.java:13: error: <identifier> expected\000d\000aimport java.lang.String;\000d\000a                       ^\000d\000a14 errors\000d\000a"; SQL statement:

CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS JSON_TABLE AS '
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.lang.String;
java.sql.ResultSet jsonTable(java.lang.String json, java.lang.String key) throws java.sql.SQLException {
    org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet rs = new org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet();
    rs.addColumn("FIELD", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
    rs.addColumn("OLD_VALUE", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
    rs.addColumn("NEW_VALUE", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);

    org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        org.json.JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        rs.addRow(
            obj.optString("field", null),
            obj.optString("oldValue", null),
            obj.optString("newValue", null)
        );
    }
    return rs;
}' [42000-224]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:514)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:489)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.handleSyntaxError(SourceCompiler.java:458)
    at org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.javaxToolsJavac(SourceCompiler.java:361)
    at org.h2.util.SourceCompiler$1.findClass(SourceCompiler.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.getClass(SourceCompiler.java:179)
    at org.h2.util.SourceCompiler.getMethod(SourceCompiler.java:244)
    at org.h2.schema.FunctionAlias.loadFromSource(FunctionAlias.java:134)
    at org.h2.schema.FunctionAlias.load(FunctionAlias.java:122)
    at org.h2.schema.FunctionAlias.init(FunctionAlias.java:109)
    at org.h2.schema.FunctionAlias.newInstanceFromSource(FunctionAlias.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateFunctionAlias.update(CreateFunctionAlias.java:49)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:256)
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.execute(RunScriptCommand.java:120)
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.update(RunScriptCommand.java:71)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:256)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:280)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:343)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:125)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:59)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:99)
    at com.avaloq.crypto.repository.rls.delegates.RlsDataSource.getConnection(RlsDataSource.java:22)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
    ... 114 more


Why?!! Why do you decide to put java code inside SQL? What made you think it would work? It is genuine question. I'm really interested in your thought process.

Hello @talex this is for h2 which java db and we have something like following already working so i thought it might also work but it seems complex methods are not possible.
'CREATE ALIAS if not exists TO_NUMBER AS '
BigDecimal toNumber(String value) {
return value == null ? null : new BigDecimal(value);
};';'

You live, you learn :) Never thought some one decide to design it this way, but well...


You must separate imports and your method with @CODE.
Because your function returns a table, you need to add java.sql.Connection as a first parameter and check its URL. If it equals to jdbc:columnlist:connection, function should return only columns of this table without actual data.

CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS JSON_TABLE AS '
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.lang.String;
@CODE
java.sql.ResultSet jsonTable(Connection conn, java.lang.String json, java.lang.String key) throws java.sql.SQLException {
    org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet rs = new org.h2.tools.SimpleResultSet();
    rs.addColumn("FIELD", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
    rs.addColumn("OLD_VALUE", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
    rs.addColumn("NEW_VALUE", Types.VARCHAR, 255, 0);
    if (conn.getMetaData().getURL().equals("jdbc:columnlist:connection")) {
        return rs;
    }
    org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        org.json.JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        rs.addRow(
            obj.optString("field", null),
            obj.optString("oldValue", null),
            obj.optString("newValue", null)
        );
    }
    return rs;
}';


You can call in only as JSON_TABLE(arg1, arg2), so you won't be able to run the same SQL even with this alias.

